# No result with AXIOMXPath on Axis 2 web service

Tags: xpath, apache-axis, axiom

I am calling a SharePoint 2010 web service from a Java Axis 2 client, using ServiceClient object (no client code generation).

I need to query the result with xPath to get the result code and other data in future developments.

I can't get a result using AXIOMXPath ...

Here is the result of the web service call :

```
<CopyIntoItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <CopyIntoItemsResult>0</CopyIntoItemsResult>
    <Results>
        <CopyResult ErrorCode="Success" DestinationUrl="http://mss2010-vm1/siteBdL/GED/obligations/obli_interne.pdf">
        </CopyResult>
    </Results>
</CopyIntoItemsResponse>
```

My code :

```
OMElement result = client.sendReceive(copyService);

if (result != null) {
    AXIOMXPath xpathExpression = new AXIOMXPath("/CopyIntoItemsResponse/Results/CopyResult/@ErrorCode"); 

    xpathExpression.addNamespace("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/");

    Object node = xpathExpression.selectNodes(result); 

    if (node != null) {
      OMAttribute attribute = (OMAttribute) node; 

      if (attribute.getAttributeValue().equals("Success")) {
        succeeded = true;
      }
    }
}
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that may cause problems here:

- When compiling the XPath expression, you are binding a namespace to the empty prefix. This is allowed by Jaxen (which is the XPath implementation used by Axiom), but it is unusual and not recommended. XML specifications such as XSLT e.g. don't allow that: in XSLT, an unqualified name appearing in an XPath expression is always interpreted as a name without namespace, even if there is a default namespace in scope. In your case there may be a problem with the `@ErrorCode` part of the XPath expression. It is expected to match the `ErrorCode` attribute which has no namespace, but I think that `@ErrorCode` actually means an attribute with local name `ErrorCode` and namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/` (I'm not 100% sure here; I would have to consult the XPath spec).
- The first `/` in your XPath expression matches the root node of the tree containing the context node (i.e. the node that you pass to `selectNodes`). For the result of `sendReceive` this will likely be a document node containing the entire SOAP message. To avoid that problem, create a new `OMDocument` and add the result of `sendReceive` to that document or use `self::CopyIntoItemsResponse/...` as the XPath expression.

Comment: I am coming back after a while to give a feedback. I can't confirm why AXIOMXPath isn't working. I have chosen to use Axiom OMElement API to get the result (using several getChildren() to "navigate" into the XML). If I had time, I would have tested your second proposition ...